# How to trigger an end point (controller) with jenkins

Tags: java, spring, jenkins

I have developed a controller which is an end point and I need it to be triggered through Jenkins, how can I do that? I'm new to Jenkins and don't have much understanding of how it works. I even read a bit about pipeline but could understand it thoroughly. A simple explanation and link to some resources would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the End point is URL, then you can trigger that using Jenkins HTTP request plugin. 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install additional plugins, you can simply use bash script with curl command to call your url endpoint in your build configuration.